# First 1,000 numbers in the arithmetic sequence 1, 4, 7, 10

Tags: java, while-loop, sequence, integer-arithmetic

I'm trying to get the first 1000 numbers in this arithmetic sequence (1,4,7,10,...)
I must do it using a while loop. I can't figure out how to set the counter so I get my 1000 numbers; I did something like this:

I'm new to programming and do not have much experience, thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[]args) /* main Method */
    {
      int s = 1;
        int sum = 3;
        while ( s < 1000 )

             {
               s = s + sum;
               System.out.println(s);
             }
}
```

Comment: The 1000th number in this sequence will be 2998, not 1000.  Keep in mind you're adding 3 each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
  int s = 0;
  int sum = 1;
  while ( s < 1000 )
  {
     s++;
     System.out.println(sum);
     sum += 3;
  }
```

In your original code, you were confusing your loop counter with your summation variable; the two should have been distinct.

Comment: Thank You , i cant vote up yet , otherwise i would  this made my day thx all.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will print the values as long as those values are less than 1000.  Not quite what you want.

Try this instead:

```
int s = 1;
System.out.println(s);
for (int i = 0; i< 999; i++)
{
    s += 3;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Note that I am calling `println` outside the loop as well to ensure we output the initial value of s (1);

**EDIT**

You need to do it with a while loop?  OK.  Try this-

```
int s = 1;
int whileCounter = 0;
System.out.println(s);
while(whileCounter < 999)
{
    s += 3;
    System.out.println(s);
    whilecounter++;
}
```

Note also that siunce we outputted the value first time around, I've reduced the count variable by 1 to 999 so we only output 1000 lines in total.

Comment: Thanks for the typo fixing Maroun.  Been a long day already. ;)

Comment: thx this would work i execute it , but i need to do it using a whileloop !

Comment: You could also say `System.out.println(s); s += 3;` to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: @AhmedBeco: `for (init; test; next) { stuff }` is almost exactly equal to `{ init; while (test) { stuff; next; } }`.  They even generate the same machine code in most if not all cases.

Comment: Code updated to use a while loop - is this for homework?  If so, please tag the question appropriately so we know how much help to give.

Answer (score 0):

An arithmetic progression or sequence is a sequence of numbers such that the difference between the consecutive terms (d) is constant. In your case, difference is 3, and the first in the sequence is 1, and you want the first 1000 sequence numbers. Now, fit the formula for the arithmetic progression:

```
a+(n-1)*d
```

For your problem, you have the following:

```
a = 1;
d = 3;
```

Code for your solution (in Java) would be as follows:

```
public class ArithProg {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    int n = 1;
    int d = 3;
    while ( n <= 1000 )  {
        System.out.println(a+(n-1)*d);
        n++;
    }
   }
}
```

The advantage with this is that, you can change the value of 'a' as well as 'd', and get a sequence of n numbers in the arithmetic progression. Hope this helps.